# Is there a way to obtain orientation of an android device and map it to coordinates in the vertical plane?

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I'm making an android game which requires knowing the absolute orientation of the device, assuming one edge stationary.
The game I'm making involves swinging the device in random directions. I need to detect the swing and the direction of swing.

It is given that at the beginning the device is in landscape mode and the edge nearest to the user (bottom edge in portrait mode) can be assumed to be stationary at all times (slight movement doesn't matter)

I only need to know the orientation of the axis running along the length of the device. the "roll" about this axis does not matter, only the orientation of this axis is needed.

I then need to map this orientation of the axis to the vertical plane of my laptop screen. That is, assuming the bottom edge (when in portrait mode) stationary and at origin, I need to know the position of the top edge in form of coordinates (x,y) which can be shown on the screen.

I have read about TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR sensor and tried the below code which uses getRotationMatrixFromVector() and getOrientation() methods to get the orientation. 
However, I couldn't understand what exactly these values are and how they can be used for the purpose.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, event.values);
        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix,
                SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, remappedRotationMatrix);
        SensorManager.getOrientation(remappedRotationMatrix, orientations);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) orientations[i] = event.values[i];
            orientations[i] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientations[i]);
}
```

Also is there any other better method than using TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR sensor? I kept the device in a a particular orientation, then after swinging the device for 2-3 seconds and keeping it in the exact same orientation, it showed deviation upto 20 degrees or so.

Comment: First, you need to learn about rotation matrix, after that task will appear clear and easy

Comment: Any detailed sources? All sources I found contain either too limited or too complex information. Thanks a lot